# why using arrays to store factorial values will output wrong values when n>=34 in C

Tags: c

The factorial values below 33 are correct.

but my code goes wrong from 34 as below:

```
34!=-134263930639604140847618609643520000000
35!=25226455986144929666651337523200000000
36!=908152415501217467999448150835200000000
37!=-9348033593545046315979581580902400000000
38!=-11627892614711760007224100074291200000000
39!=18958590953758640281739902897356800000000
40!=-100649821150345611269596115894272000000000
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 100
int Fact(int a[], int n);
int a[N] = { 0 };

int main() {
    int n, i, j, index;
    printf("input n(1≤n≤40):");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { //printf every factorial value from 1 to 40
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            a[j] = 0; /* reset the array as 0 in every loop */
        index = Fact(a, i);/*Calculates the factorial value and stores the result in array,
                        returning the array index of the highest bit of the factorial value*/
        printf("\n%d!=", i);
        for (j = index; j >= 1; --j)
            printf("%d", a[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int Fact(int a[], int n) {
    int i, j, temp, index = 1;
    a[1] = 1; //the index of array starts from 1, not 0
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (j = 1; j <= index; j++)
            a[j] *= i; //Multiply each position of the array by 1 to i
        for (j = 1; j < index; ++j) {
            if (a[j] > 9) { //Judging if every position of array needs a carry
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j] % 10;
                a[j + 1] += temp / 10;
            }
        }
        if (a[index] > 9) { //Judging if the highest position needs a carry
            temp = a[index];
            a[index] = a[index] % 10;
            a[++index] += temp / 10;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Expected output:

```
1! =    1
2! =    2
3! =    6
4! =    24
5! =    120
6! =    720
7! =    5040
8! =    40320
9! =    362880
10! =   3628800
11! =   39916800
12! =   479001600
13! =   6227020800
14! =   87178291200
15! =   1307674368000
16! =   20922789888000
17! =   355687428096000
18! =   6402373705728000
19! =   121645100408832000
20! =   2432902008176640000
21! =   51090942171709440000
22! =   1124000727777607680000
23! =   25852016738884976640000
24! =   620448401733239439360000
25! =   15511210043330985984000000
26! =   403291461126605635584000000
27! =   10888869450418352160768000000
28! =   304888344611713860501504000000
29! =   8841761993739701954543616000000
30! =   265252859812191058636308480000000
31! =   8222838654177922817725562880000000
32! =   263130836933693530167218012160000000
33! =   8683317618811886495518194401280000000
34! =   295232799039604140847618609643520000000
35! =   10333147966386144929666651337523200000000
36! =   371993326789901217467999448150835200000000
37! =   13763753091226345046315979581580902400000000
38! =   523022617466601111760007224100074291200000000
39! =   20397882081197443358640281739902897356800000000
40! =   815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000
```

Comment: What is the maximum value int can represent, since you start seeing negative numbers, you are probably overflowing your integer.  If you change to an unsigned int you can increase the range of representable positive values.

Comment: Carry occurs whenever the result of multiplying two numbers is greater than 9,so  every number in the array is a single digit. Thus, I don't think the cause of negative numbers is int overflow. @Jonathon K

Comment: Int overflow is the only way you can get negative numbers when multiplying two numbers greater than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `Fact` function, an overflow is happening in this part of the code:

```
            if (a[index] > 9) {//Judging if the highest position needs a carry
                temp = a[index];
                a[index] = a[index] % 10;
                a[++index] += temp / 10;
            }
```

**Solution:** Change the `if` to a `while` loop.

```
            while(a[index] > 9) {  //   <---- if to while
                temp = a[index];
                a[index] = a[index] % 10;
                a[++index] += temp / 10;
            }
```

---

**Explanation:**

As far as I can understand, the `a` array *should* contain each digit of the resulting factorial. It's size is initialized to `N` which is 100. The internal representation of the digits are also reversed.

```
10! = 362880 = [0, 8, 8, 2, 6, 3, ... rest of unused indices]
                               ^
                            a[index]
```

In the snippet above, `a[index]` points to the most significant digit.

You are only taking care of `a[index]` once if it is greater than `9`. In my tests, `a[index]` slowly creeps to become a big number. After doing the inside procedure once, `a[index] > 9` still hold true for factorial of `n>=15`. Thus, you should perform the inside procedure *until* the condition no longer holds true.

This is a print out of the significant digits of the `a` array:

```
1!=1
2!=2
3!=6
4!=2 4
5!=1 2 0
6!=7 2 0
7!=5 0 4 0
8!=4 0 3 2 0
9!=3 6 2 8 8 0
10!=3 6 2 8 8 0 0
11!=3 9 9 1 6 8 0 0
12!=4 7 9 0 0 1 6 0 0
13!=6 2 2 7 0 2 0 8 0 0
14!=8 7 1 7 8 2 9 1 2 0 0
15!=13 0 7 6 7 4 3 6 8 0 0 0
16!=20 9 2 2 7 8 9 8 8 8 0 0 0
17!=35 5 6 8 7 4 2 8 0 9 6 0 0 0
18!=64 0 2 3 7 3 7 0 5 7 2 8 0 0 0
19!=121 6 4 5 1 0 0 4 0 8 8 3 2 0 0 0
20!=243 2 9 0 2 0 0 8 1 7 6 6 4 0 0 0 0
21!=510 9 0 9 4 2 1 7 1 7 0 9 4 4 0 0 0 0
22!=1124 0 0 0 7 2 7 7 7 7 6 0 7 6 8 0 0 0 0
23!=2585 2 0 1 6 7 3 8 8 8 4 9 7 6 6 4 0 0 0 0
24!=6204 4 8 4 0 1 7 3 3 2 3 9 4 3 9 3 6 0 0 0 0
25!=15511 2 1 0 0 4 3 3 3 0 9 8 5 9 8 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
26!=40329 1 4 6 1 1 2 6 6 0 5 6 3 5 5 8 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
27!=108888 6 9 4 5 0 4 1 8 3 5 2 1 6 0 7 6 8 0 0 0 0 0 0
28!=304888 3 4 4 6 1 1 7 1 3 8 6 0 5 0 1 5 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
29!=884176 1 9 9 3 7 3 9 7 0 1 9 5 4 5 4 3 6 1 6 0 0 0 0 0 0
30!=2652528 5 9 8 1 2 1 9 1 0 5 8 6 3 6 3 0 8 4 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
31!=8222838 6 5 4 1 7 7 9 2 2 8 1 7 7 2 5 5 6 2 8 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
32!=26313083 6 9 3 3 6 9 3 5 3 0 1 6 7 2 1 8 0 1 2 1 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
33!=86833176 1 8 8 1 1 8 8 6 4 9 5 5 1 8 1 9 4 4 0 1 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
34!=-1342639306 3 9 6 0 4 1 4 0 8 4 7 6 1 8 6 0 9 6 4 3 5 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
35!=25226455 9 8 6 1 4 4 9 2 9 6 6 6 6 5 1 3 3 7 5 2 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
36!=90815241 5 5 0 1 2 1 7 4 6 7 9 9 9 4 4 8 1 5 0 8 3 5 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
37!=-934803359 3 5 4 5 0 4 6 3 1 5 9 7 9 5 8 1 5 8 0 9 0 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
38!=-1162789261 4 7 1 1 7 6 0 0 0 7 2 2 4 1 0 0 0 7 4 2 9 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
39!=189585909 5 3 7 5 8 6 4 0 2 8 1 7 3 9 9 0 2 8 9 7 3 5 6 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
40!=-1006498211 5 0 3 4 5 6 1 1 2 6 9 5 9 6 1 1 5 8 9 4 2 7 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

As you can see, the most significant digit `a[index]` is overflowing. This output is generated by just adding a space in between digits when you output the resulting array.

```
    int main(){
        // ...
        // for loop
            // calc factorial

            /* output the result */
           printf("\n%d!=", i);
            for (j = index; j >= 1; --j)
                printf("%d ", a[j]); //     <---- add space between digits


        // end for loop
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your feekback.But I tried your solution,the problem remained.Maybe I misunderstood or didn't understand your answer clearly. Could you add a little more to my question?

Comment: @MMJJQQ Sorry to hear that. All I did was change the `if` to `while` and it worked. I edited the post to show what i mean.

Comment: @MMJJQQ did you try changing the first or second`if` in the `fact` method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe you can get what you wanted :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

#define MAX 3000 

int str[MAX]; 

void calculateFactorial(int n); 

int main() 
{ 
  int n; 
  //while (scanf("%d", &n) != EOF) { 
  for(n = 0; n <=40; n++) { 
      printf("%d!=",n);
      if(n == 0) { 
        printf("1\n"); 
      } else { 
        calculateFactorial(n); 
      } 
  printf("\n");
  } 
  return 0; 
} 

void calculateFactorial(int n) 
{ 
  int i, j, temp, c, len; 
  memset(str, 0, sizeof(str)); 
  str[1] = 1; 
  for (i = 2, len = 1; i <= n; i ++) { 
      for (j = 1, c = 0; j <= len; j ++) { 
          temp = str[j] * i + c; 
          str[j] = temp % 10; 
          c = temp / 10; 
      } 
      while(c > 0){
        str[j ++] = c % 10; 
        c /= 10; 
      } 
      len = j - 1; 
  } 
  for (i = len; i >= 1; i --) { 
    printf("%d", str[i]); 
  } 
  printf("\n"); 
}
```

The output is :

```
0!=1

1!=1

2!=2

3!=6

4!=24

5!=120

6!=720

7!=5040

8!=40320

9!=362880

10!=3628800

11!=39916800

12!=479001600

13!=6227020800

14!=87178291200

15!=1307674368000

16!=20922789888000

17!=355687428096000

18!=6402373705728000

19!=121645100408832000

20!=2432902008176640000

21!=51090942171709440000

22!=1124000727777607680000

23!=25852016738884976640000

24!=620448401733239439360000

25!=15511210043330985984000000

26!=403291461126605635584000000

27!=10888869450418352160768000000

28!=304888344611713860501504000000

29!=8841761993739701954543616000000

30!=265252859812191058636308480000000

31!=8222838654177922817725562880000000

32!=263130836933693530167218012160000000

33!=8683317618811886495518194401280000000

34!=295232799039604140847618609643520000000

35!=10333147966386144929666651337523200000000

36!=371993326789901217467999448150835200000000

37!=13763753091226345046315979581580902400000000

38!=523022617466601111760007224100074291200000000

39!=20397882081197443358640281739902897356800000000

40!=815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000
```

## or if you want to correct your code :

try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 3000
int Fact(int a[], int n);
int a[N] = { 0 };
int main() {
    int n, i, j, index;
    printf("input n(1≤n≤40):");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {//printf every factorial value from 1 to 40
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            a[j] = 0;/*reset the array as 0 in every loop*/
        index = Fact(a, i);/*Calculates the factorial value and stores the result in array,
                        returning the array index of the highest bit of the factorial value*/
        printf("\n%d!=", i);
        for (j = index; j >= 1; --j)
            printf("%d", a[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int Fact(int a[], int n) {
    int i, j, temp, index = 1;
    a[1] = 1;//the index of array starts from 1,not 0
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (j = 1; j <= index; j++)
            a[j] *= i;//Multiply each position of the array by 1 to i
        for (j = 1; j < index; ++j) {
            if (a[j] > 9) {//Judging if every position of array needs a carry
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j] % 10;
                a[j + 1] += temp / 10;
            }
        }
        while (a[index] > 9) {//Judging if the highest position needs a carry
            temp = a[index];
            a[index] = a[index] % 10;
            a[++index] += temp / 10;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

The output is :

```
0!=1

1!=1

2!=2

3!=6

4!=24

5!=120

6!=720

7!=5040

8!=40320

9!=362880

10!=3628800

11!=39916800

12!=479001600

13!=6227020800

14!=87178291200

15!=1307674368000

16!=20922789888000

17!=355687428096000

18!=6402373705728000

19!=121645100408832000

20!=2432902008176640000

21!=51090942171709440000

22!=1124000727777607680000

23!=25852016738884976640000

24!=620448401733239439360000

25!=15511210043330985984000000

26!=403291461126605635584000000

27!=10888869450418352160768000000

28!=304888344611713860501504000000

29!=8841761993739701954543616000000

30!=265252859812191058636308480000000

31!=8222838654177922817725562880000000

32!=263130836933693530167218012160000000

33!=8683317618811886495518194401280000000

34!=295232799039604140847618609643520000000

35!=10333147966386144929666651337523200000000

36!=371993326789901217467999448150835200000000

37!=13763753091226345046315979581580902400000000

38!=523022617466601111760007224100074291200000000

39!=20397882081197443358640281739902897356800000000

40!=815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000
```

Comment: Thank you.Maybe your code did work,but I just don't want a code that could work,I would rather want to correct my own code :)

Comment: @MMJJQQ, my answer updated.Hope it is useful for you.